# Cordova - check_reqs module is missing for platform. Skipping it

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, windows-10

I am having issues with a Cordova application originally built on Ubuntu but when I try to load the very same Cordova application onto my Windows 10 machine I get into issues.

When I run the following command this is the response I get :

```
$ cordova requirements
```

//output from cmd

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed
Android target: installed android-17,android-18,android-19,android-20,android-21,android-22,android-23,android-24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:17,Google Inc.:Google APIs:18,Google Inc.:Google APIs:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23
Gradle: installed

Requirements check results for browser:
Check failed for browser due to Failed to check requirements for browser platform. check_reqs module is missing for the platform. Skipping it...
Error: Some of the requirements check failed
```

I have tried to manually reinstall the browser by using the following commands :

```
$ cordova platform remove browser
$ cordova platform add browser
```

Can anyone suggest what I should do??

When I run the application using Cordova emulate OR run the application opens I can see the html/js/css code within the console but the screen goes white, then all gray (as if it is CSS related) but the VERY same application works on my colleagues Ubuntu machine which is very strange indeed - any ideas???

Running:
Node version 4.4.7
Cordova version 6.3.1

Comment: facing the same problem in mac

Comment: Not sure, but try creating a fresh project and then loading your content into it (copy the src folder). I've had this issue before. It was fixed when I created the application from scratch (and then imported the custom code). I believe it has something to do with the application initialization in a particular OS.